# navigation appears when I scroll down page--it should appear on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The navigation bar appears when I scroll down the page, but I want it to appear on page load.

Here is jQuery code I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 20) {
            $("#floating-nav-content").slideUp(400);
        } else {
            $("#floating-nav-content").slideDown(600);
        }

    });
</script>
```

Here is link to where I am using this.
http://dev.servicescart.com/about

This link is only for the internal page of this site, like I said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that to be applied on Page load, remove that scroll event and hook the action to document ready event.

Documentation for [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) event

> Description: Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully
>   loaded.

```
$(function(){
    // do your logic for slide action
});
```

Comment: thank you rahul for answer, kindly can you send me updated code, i mean what you explained send code for that!, i will chose you answer instantly as a best answer.

Comment: can't you modify my code directly, i will test and let you know if works!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Rahul, I did it. Here is code I used to load navigation on page load, not with scroll down wait.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#floating-nav-content").slideDown(600);

});
</script>
```